# Why is this async function not behaving asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, synchronization

I am learning Javascript. I am not used to asynchronous programming so having a hard time here. Here's my code:

```js
var x = 0;

async function increment(x) {
  ++x;
  for (var i = 0; i < 999999999; i = i + 1);
  console.log('value of x is: ' + x);
};

increment(x);

console.log('Out of the function');
```

Expectation: 'Out of the function' gets printed instantly. 'value of x...' takes some time.
Reality: 'value of x...' gets printed first after a delay. Then 'Out of the function' is printed.

My question is, why isn't increment() being called asynchronously? Why is it blocking the last console.log?

Comment: Most of the answers seem to be about a solution. But I was rather looking forward to some explanations to why my expectation is not correct. I thought whenever I use async, that function will NOT block next synchronous execution - irrespective of the use of await. I just don't want increment function to block last console.log()

Comment: If you put async without await, the function will behave like a normal (synchronous) function. So, `increment(x)` will block last console.log(). I have put a link to MDN in my answer, may be its helpful to understand better.

Comment: @FarhanFuad check out my answer, especially the Bob-Alice part.

Comment: It happens because at no point in your function you ever do something asynchronous, you never yield execution back to the event loop. Keep in mind that Javascript is single-threaded. If you insert something like `await new Promise(setImmediate)` after every 1000th iteration or so, you'll give some other code (like your console.log) a chance to execute instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TL;DR: You must `await something` inside the async function to make it async.

```js
var x = 0;

async function increment(x) {
  await null;  // <-- ADD THIS LINE
  ++x;
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i = i + 1);
  console.log('value of x is: ' + x);
};

increment(x);

console.log('Out of the function');
```

Longer version:

First let's clarify one thing: JS runtime is an event-loop based single threaded runtime, this mean **no concurrency/paralell code execution** (unless you use `Worker` or `child_process`, that's another topic).

Now to the asynchronous part. The `async-await` is just a handy syntax sugar that under the hood uses `Promise` and `Generator`, which in turn calls the event loop scheduling API provided by platfrom. In Node.js that API is `process.nextTick` while in browser it's `setImmediate`.

Through these APIs jobs are scheduled, buffered in the **micro task queue**, which will be tapped and executed by the event loop when idle. Thus the asynchronicity is in fact just scheduling.

---

With this knowledge let's come back to your case.

the `async function` keyword does two things:

1. it forces the function to return a `Promise`
2. it allows you to use the `await` keyword inside the function body

The actually scheduling part happens when you use the `await` keyword. What it does, is to send a scheduled task to the micro task queue, which will always be a callback to a `Promise.then()` call (in above example I send `null`, it'll be auto-wrapped to be `Promise.resolve(null)`), then pause the execution of current function, and wait until that promise resolves to continue execution of the rest.

So if you don't involve the event-loop scheduler by using `await` keyword, then execution order will stay normal. Thus explain your case.

---

If you do undertand that `async` function is just syntax sugar around `Promise`, the next often seen misunderstanding is the execution order of `new Promise(callback)`.

Case 1:

```js
new Promise((resolve) => {
  console.log('Bob comes first!')
  resolve(null)
})

console.log('Alice comes first!')
```

**Q**: Who comes first?
**A**: Bob comes first.

Case 2:

```js
new Promise((resolve) => {
  resolve(null)
}).then(() => console.log('Bob comes first!'))


console.log('Alice comes first!')
```

**Q**: Who comes first?
**A**: This time Alice comes first.

Case 1 corresponds to your code. `async` wrap the function into a promise's callback, but if you don't `.then()` that callback is executed immediately, in normal order.

Case 2 corresponds to my `await null` example. Which breaks up the function body into two parts, one inside `new Promise(callback)`, the rest inside `promise.then(callback)`. And the execution order of the latter is deferred.

Answer (score 2):

`async` function has no `await`, so function will run synchronously. If no await is provided, javascript does not throw any error.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Description)

> The body of an async function can be thought of as being split by zero
> or more await expressions. Top-level code, up to and including the
> first await expression (if there is one), is run synchronously. In
> this way, **an async function without an await expression will run
> synchronously**

Convert it to something like below and you will see expected behaviour:

```js
 var x = 0;
async function increment(x) {
  ++x;
  await setTimeout(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 999999999; i = i + 1);
  });
  console.log('value of x is: ' + x);
};

increment(x);

console.log('Out of the function');
```

Comment: @adiga, It is an example to convey the concept and I believe it's serving the purpose.

Comment: @adiga, you mean if I remove await, it will still log "Out of the function"  before  "value of x"?

Comment: oh, no worries mate. I thought I missed something conceptually.

Comment: This is a misleading answer. You use `setTimeout` to tap into event-loop scheduling API, which would indeed give you async code execution order, but that has nothing to do with `async-await` mechanism. Putting the two together is very confusing.

Comment: You can `await whateverAsLongAsItsAnExpression` to make this example work.

Answer (score 0):

Because JavaScript is not multithreaded I suppose.

You could try with a JQuery approach (maybe) or learn about Web Workers
The very first resource I found googlin' around:
https://medium.com/techtrument/multithreading-javascript-46156179cf9a

Answer (score 0):

That's because a function being asynchronous doesn't mean that it will always **end** last.

Wrap the async console.log in a setTimeout and you'll see the last console.log print first.

```js
var x = 0;

async function increment(x) {
  ++x;
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('value of x is: ' + x);
  }, 1000);
};

increment(x);

console.log('Out of the function');
```

Here is a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ldjma3s8/

Answer (score 0):

You should use await. From the official JS documentation: "The keyword await makes JavaScript wait until that promise settles and returns its result."

Also if it seems a bit strange but you can achieve your result with this:

```
const x = 0;
async function f(x) {
  try {
    ++x;
    for (i = 0; i < 999; i = i + 1)
      console.log('value of x is:', await i);

  } catch (e) {
    console.log('error', e);
  }
};

f(x);
console.log('Out');
```

Comment: `Out` gets logged before `value of x is`

Comment: Yes it is basically what he's asksing, that is: "Expectation: 'Out of the function' gets printed instantly. 'value of x...' takes some time."

Answer (score 0):

The async keyword makes a function return a promise or 'thenable'. You need to await your promise increment.

Top level await is proposed but until we have it You would need your call to be within another async function or to use then.

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await

```
var x = 0;

async function increment(x) {
  ++x;
  for (var i = 0; i < 999999999; i = i + 1);
  console.log('value of x is: ' + x);
};

async function waitThenLog() {
  await increment(x);
  console.log('Out of the function');
}

waitThenLog();


// or...

increment(x).then(() => console.log('Out of the function'));
```

Comment: Ironically to achieve the desired effect you could also omit the async on "async function increment" as then the increment call would be blocking.